# Adjective for something that can be responded to

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

What is an adjective for something that can be responded to? I tried *respondable* but it looks like it isn't in the dictionary and it felt wrong anyway.

---

**Update:** I need to use it in the context of responding to user requests by the company staff. So the user request is [insert the word here] if there is an option (like a checkbox) to respond to the request.

Comment: According to NOAD: **answerable** (*adj.*) (of a question) able to be answered. That might work for what you want, but it's hard to know for sure, because you've provided so little context in your question. You could be talking about a question on an exam, a question by a lawyer to a defendant, a field on a website's feedback form, a line in a script of a play, an open-ended question by a stand-up comic, etc. I'm not sure "answerable" would best word under all possible contexts.

Comment: An *event*? An event can be responded to?!

Comment: @J.R. I'd say *answerable* suffers the same limitations as *responsible* -- how is it any better?

Comment: @Kris: Examine the edit history of this question, with particular attention paid to Version 1. When I made my comment, none of the updates had been made yet; in fact, my initial comment that may have prompted some of the later improvements.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It felt wrong because *-able* forms adjectives from transitive verbs — *doable, drivable, killable, reversable, callable, wearable*. But *respond* is not a transitive verb. Find a transitive synonym, and then slap the *-able* onto it. For example, *answerable, fieldable, addressable, handleable, acknowledgeable*.

Comment: thanks. I guess the best choice in this context will be either _answerable_ or _addressable_

Comment: _actionable_ is another alternative

Comment: oh that is a good rule.  -able only works with transitive verbs.  is this a known rule? or just a general observation?

Answer (score 3):

The nearest you’re likely to get is *answerable*, in the sense ‘Capable of answering requirements, purposes’ (Oxford English Dictionary).

Comment: I'd say *answerable* suffers the same limitations as *responsible* -- how is it any better?

Comment: @Kris. It's true that both words can imply a sense of duty, but my intuition is that _responsible_ does so more forcefully. As so often, if time and inclination allowed, a thorough corpus search might provide the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update, you might consider:

> **feasible**: *possible to do easily or conveniently*
>
> **workable**: *capable of producing the desired effect or result; practicable; feasible*

Other options might include *viable*, *achievable*, or *attainable*.

<sub>(Definitions from NOAD)</sub>

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice it made the question even more ambiguous. Updated again.

Comment: Or perhaps **serviceable**.

Answer (score 1):

*Respondable* is already a word. Found in formal as well as informal, technical as well as non-technical writing.

1 [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/i/i18n_scopes-0.4.0/Respondable.html) Class: **Respondable**

2 [Lan Shi](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0929119910000830): **Respondable** risk and incentives for CEOs: The role of information-collection and decision-making

> This paper examines the incentive provision when the agent **can respond** to risk by exerting effort to collect information about the underlying state and making corresponding decisions. Such effort is shown to be more valuable in a riskier environment and incentives can increase with **“respondable”** risk. The relation between incentives and risk is more positive when the agent's effort is more effective in collecting information or in acting upon it. Using data on chief executive officers (CEOs), I find that incentives for CEOs increase with industry-wide risk, a measure of **respondable** risk. The positive relation diminishes when the CEO is less able to collect information or is less effective in acting upon it.

3 [RealWired!](http://realwiredinc.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/you-need-to-be-respondable/) You Need to be **“Respondable”**

> It’s not a typo.  The word I’m using and intended to use is “respondable”.  I’m using it as an adjective and I suggest you adopt it that way too.   Here’s what I’m suggesting.  If you are communicating, particularly in the world of social media, you have a responsibility to make what you put out there respondable.   Hint:  If you are going to adopt what I suggest, you better add “respondable” to your processor’s dictionary, because I assure you it’s not there and that alone will drive you nuts.

4 [V-REP](http://www.v-rep.eu/helpFiles/en/designingDynamicSimulations.htm) Static/non-static, **respondable**/ **non-respondable** shape behaviors and interactions

> During dynamic simulation, static shapes will not be influenced (i.e. their position relative to their parent object is fixed), whereas non-static shapes will be directly influenced by gravity or other constraints (e.g. dynamically enabled joints, see hereafter). **Respondable** shapes influence each other during dynamic collision (i.e. they produce a mutual collision reaction, they will bounce off each other). Following figure illustrates the static/non-static, respondable/non-respondable behaviors ...
>   [image]

5 [quora.com](http://www.quora.com/When-will-Google+-allow-me-to-receive-respondable-text-message-updates-like-Facebook-notifications) When will Google+ allow me to receive **respondable** text message updates like Facebook notifications?

> Facebook mobile forwards me status updates from specific friends, and if I reply to that text, it will post my response on their status.

6 [Quiplip](http://fab.com/inspiration/respondable-holiday-card-set): **Respondable** Holiday Card Set

> Quiplip’s greeting cards deliver a diverse range of sentiments with a dinosauric dose of snark to wash ‘em down. [...] recipients will be absolutely overflowing with... you'll find out which emotion when they send the return postcard back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the update, something along the lines of *legitimate* or *reasonable* seems most correct.